# Connecting Bluetooth Health Devices with Android Application

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to Integrate two Health devices like Bp monitor and Weightscale??Can We Register both health deviecs at the same time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically possible but haven't found a generic app supporting multiple type of sensors(devices). Haven't seen an app that records both Bluetooth Blood Pressure monitors, bluetooth oximeters, bluetooth weight scales and bluetooth heart rate straps etc. There are apps from suppliers of sensors but haven't seen one supporting multiple sensors. Some sports apps support of recording heart rate straps and oximeters but not any other.

Technically they all use generic protocols and streams for one type of sensor but seems like developers are not interested in all types of sensors, not even most.